# Permissions denied for image upload

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, file-permissions, image-uploading

I'm trying to receive an image from a user and then upload it to my Amazon S3 account, but I'm getting the error `Warning: move_uploaded_file(/items) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied` from Zend Framework. I set the permissions on the folder to 777 through FTP but I'm still getting the error. Here's the code producing the error, on the off chance that it makes a difference. The error is coming up on the receive, I would assume. How can I get rid of this error?

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
        $upload->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array('minwidth'  => 100,
                                                  'maxwidth'  => 1000,
                                                  'minheight' => 100,
                                                  'maxheight' => 1000), 'image')
         ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg')
         ->addValidator('Count', false, array('min'=>0, 'max'=>2));

if($upload->isUploaded('image')){ //Pic was uploaded
                if($upload->isValid('image')){ //Pic is valid
                    echo "Pic provided is valid.";
                    $upload->addFilter('Rename',array('target'=>"/items/{$item_id}_nla.jpg",'overwrite'=>true));
                    $upload->receive();
                    $pic = "/items/{$item_id}_nla.jpg";
                    $s3->putObject("media.completeset.com/images/items/{$item_id}_nla.jpg", $pic,
                                    array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER => Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
                                          Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER => "image/jpeg"));
                    echo "Pic is uploaded.";
                }
                echo "Pic is invalid.";
            }
```

Comment: You need to set the correct permissions on the folder...

Comment: are you sure you had permission to set the permissions on that folder?

Comment: Even with permissions set to 777 it still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the directory so it is absolute:

```
$projectRootDirectory = "/var/www/myproject";
// ...
$upload->addFilter('Rename',array('target'=> $projectRootDirectory."/items/{$item_id}_nla.jpg",'overwrite'=>true));
// ...
$pic = $projectRootDirectory."/items/{$item_id}_nla.jpg";
```

Or remove the first `/` if you are already in the project root.

Comment: Creating an absolute path solved it, I guess it was just trying to upload to a different folder than what I thought it was.